# blank PNG UIImageView

Tags: iphone, ios4, uiimageview, uiimage

Hopefully a quick one for someone?! I am TOTALLY at a loss. 
I have two images,

p1-slide01.png and p3-slide01.png

Both PNG images open in Preview and when I click on them in Xcode, I see them. They are there. They are in the right folder etc.

Yet, when I do `myImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"p1-slide01.png"]` it doesn't work. It does however work for p3-slide01.png. The code is no different. I have generated the PNG images via an export in PowerPoint. They look fine everywhere.

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?! The UIImageViews are declared and retained in the .h file.

[UPDATE] - I renamed the image to "testy.png" and it loaded. Yet when I changed it back to the original p1-slide01.png - it comes up blank. It's like there are cached images somewhere (I've used these file names in another app?!) - do I just need to change file names?!

Comment: Can you try it without the extension? `[UIImage imageNamed:@"p1-slide01"]`

Comment: Do a clean build and you should be sorted.

Comment: yep - cleaning sorted it. Can't believe I wasted nearly 3 hours on this "problem"!!!! Thanks :)

Comment: Xcode caching, you'll learn to love to hate it. When in doubt, clean and rebuild; also delete the app off your device before building & running again.

Comment: @Rog:- Yup Rog is right,whenever you stuck to this type of problem ,just try to do 2 things delete your build and clean the target.It then removes your old dependencies of target..........

Comment: Also double check your filename case. All my devices and simulator worked correctly except one iPad2 device. Very strange!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you clean your build, there may be an additional `p1-slide01.png` loitering around.

Answer (score 0):

Also, change them to JPEGs and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Changing the filetype would not make any difference.

Comment: @WrightsCS: I had a similar problem where when I changed the filetype, It would display on the screen properly.